# Console.Writeline() shortcut shifting

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2022

Visual Studio 2022 automatically shifts curly braces at bottom and `Console.Writeline()` if I use cw instead of typing `Console.Writeline()` manually.

Example is in this screenshot:

[image: (photo)]

I tried to ask ChatGPT about it, but did not get a correct solution.

Added a video of this trouble, where all braces are correct:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lApVT9GOr6WBgIhgTW6GVgcSVAlus2Ih/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I don't see that behavior. Make sure you don't have mismatched curly braces in the file.

Comment: Just format it back manually.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft, Edited the question: added a link to video, where I showed a problem. Braces are correct, I suppose

Comment: Doesn't happen for me. Version 17.7.1. Are your tabs settings set to the default?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft I don't have VS2022 to test with, but it looks like the OP is using a nonstandard tab stop of 5 spaces.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft
I don`t know how to solve problem in "Settings",  I tried to change settings in tabs and intellisense sections, but had no result.
But I dropped VS 2022 settings to default and it helped.
Anyway, thank you!